# Why won't my raspberry pi boot after reformatting the SD?

Tags: boot

The scenario is that I attempted to reformat the SD card that my raspberry pi was using to explore the other OS's that are out there.  After I reformatted the SD and mounted the SD exactly like before, however now the rpi wont boot up.  The power light is solid red and it is connected.  Any insight?

edit: Should have mentioned I'm on a mac.

Comment: This needs more information. What OS did you try and put on it?

Answer (score 3):

If you reformatted the SD card and didn't put another operating system on it, the RasPi will not boot. The RasPi needs an operating system on the SD card in order to boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you reformatted an SD Card on a Mac, it's possible the card was formatted into HFS+ instead of the Windows disk format it no doubt shipped with. That didn't happen for me by default, it seems to stick with what was already there. But if you somehow altered the disk format, that would cause a problem.